# jQuery UI sortable list in overflow hidden container. Dragged element jumping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a container that is with overflow: hidden and can fill up with maximum 6 elements. When I sort form 1 to 6 elemnts it is working but when elements are transformedY, sortable is going crazy after drag. It's hard to describe so just look at my fiddle:

```js
$(".barbox").sortable();


$("#scrolled").children(".bar").css("transform", "translateY(-153px)");
```

```css
.barbox
{
    height: 307px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1
{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.bar
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<h1>Example 1:</h1>
    <div class="barbox">
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 1.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 2.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 3.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 4.</div></div> 
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 5.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 6.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 7.</div></div> 
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 8.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 9.</div></div>
    </div>
 <h1>Example 2:</h1>
    <div class="barbox" id="scrolled">
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 1.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 2.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 3.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 4.</div></div> 
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 5.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 6.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 7.</div></div> 
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 8.</div></div>
        <div class="bar"><div class="task">Task 9.</div></div>
    </div>
```

How you can see, dragged element in example 2 is jumping up.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: For what do you need that `transform` feature? If it's buggy - delete it.

Comment: I need it for scrolling/sliding my list. Example 2 is like "after 3 slides down".

Comment: I would like to help you... give me your e-mail so we can speak freely.

Comment: I saved it. I will contact with you soon.

Comment: @Edenwave why are you using transform?

Comment: @Novice Look at my 2nd answer in that post.